# How to check if a new mysql column has been made (Based on timer)

Tags: c#, mysql

I would like to know how I would go about checking a mysql database for new entries x amount of minutes?

Comment: The question is too vague or has many possible answers. Please be more specific on the problem statement.

Comment: You mean "rows" not "columns"?

Comment: Correct, I want to make a timer which checks for new rows which we not in the last check.

Comment: If you wanna do this at the sql server end, then use triggers for this purpose and if you wanna do this in your code then create a counter, save the initial count of your columns by getting a record from that table then after some time check again and compare it with your previous counter.